# Preventing redirecting from the start

Tags: grails, redirect, controller, gsp

I'm experience some auto redirecting at the page when it first loaded.

These are my codes:

```
def editUser = {
    if(params.account_expired != null )
    {
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE user SET expired='"+params.account_expired+"'"


    def update = sql.executeUpdate(updateQuery)
    redirect (action: listUser)
    [update:update]


    }

    else
    {

    }
 }
```

so what happen is, when the page got loaded, it auto redirect back to listuser page. This is actually an edituser page and I want it to stay there until the user clicks a button. And then redirect to listuser. Any idea guys?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you should not use groovy sql. Defeats the whole purpose of Grails apps being database independent. Also you are highly prone to sql injection with that code above. Switch to using HQL or GORM methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use POST method to send update, and GET to show form (as it suggested by W3C, and used in Grails by default). So you can use:

```
def editUser = {
  if (request.method == 'GET') {
     render(view: 'editUser')
  } else if (request.method == 'POST') {
     //.... current code
  }
}
```

by default Grails creates POST form, when you're using `<g:form` tag, but if you're using plain HTML tags, you should specify POST method as:

```
<form method="POST">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what your code is supposed to do, because you have this executed:

```
redirect (action: listUser)
```

If you want it stay in editUser page, you should remove it. Then

```
[Query1:Query1]
```

will render editUser.gsp with this parameter passed.

Comment: So how do I redirect myself to the listuser page instead of staying in the same page.

Comment: You can not render a page and redirect to another page at the same time. Your purpose is: "I want it to stay there until the user clicks a button." So put a link or a form submit in the button with "[action: 'listPage']" parameter.

Comment: Is it okay if you were to show me an answer with example? This will benefit other users too. I will try it on my own at the same time.

Comment: I tried, but I think you need to rewrite your code first. When I was trying to add an example, I found that your code was set all the user instances to the same expire status, listUser action in the redirect should be quoted, and Query1 properties is not defined...... That code just won't got compiled successfully. And, As James Kleeh suggested, there are GORM methods which enable a better database access method.

Comment: Sorry i made some edits already. I think i copied wrongly. So sorry, I'm still trying it out.